# Cannot start apache from lampstack

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.4, amazon-lightsail

I just installed bitnami-lampstack-7.4 on my linux box.

I cannot start apache, I'm getting

```
/opt/bitnami/apache/bin/httpd: error while loading shared libraries: libiconv.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

libiconv.so.2 is located on /opt/bitnami/common/lib, so I exported the library path

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH/opt/bitnami/common/lib

echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/opt/bitnami/common/lib/
```

and I'm still get the same error message, when I do the following command, I see it

```
ldd /opt/bitnami/apache/bin/httpd
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff3f326000)
libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007f079717c000)
libaprutil-1.so.0 => /opt/bitnami/common/lib/libaprutil-1.so.0 (0x00007f0796f45000)
libapr-1.so.0 => /opt/bitnami/common/lib/libapr-1.so.0 (0x00007f0796d06000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f0796ce4000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f0796b10000)
libexpat.so.1 => /opt/bitnami/common/lib/libexpat.so.1 (0x00007f07968dc000)
libiconv.so.2 => /opt/bitnami/common/lib/libiconv.so.2 (0x00007f07965eb000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f07965e5000)
librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f07965db000)
libcrypt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt.so.1 (0x00007f07965a0000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f07972bc000)
```

Please help.

Comment: why do you want to use this kind? it only makes things complicated. why do you not want to use the native installation of the distribution?